# Где лучше хранить фотографии для сайта агентства недвижимости

Tags: sql

Не могу выбрать более разумный путь хранения фотографий для агентства недвижимости, так как фотографий там очень много. Что лучше выбрать, хранение на хостинге(бд) и плата за такие большие объемы или хранение на каком-либо облачном сервисе и вытаскивание оттуда фоток посредством ссылки на них. Но доселе я так и не нашел, на какой из платформ так можно реализовать, так как ссылки оттуда взять нельзя, они хранятся в виде файлов

Comment: в чем вы видите преимущества хранения в БД ? и сколько много в штуках и гигабайтах

Comment: Ну файлы как бы лучше хранить в файловой системе. Дополнительное дисковое пространство на хостинге будет дешевле, чем такой же объём, но в БД.

Comment: @teran я не вижу преимущества именно здесь, просто пытаюсь выбрать лучший путь) на каждый дом приходится около 50-60 фотографий, а домов там может быть от 100. в гигабайтах пока не узнавал

Comment: Никогда не храните картинки в БД, если вам не надо их каждый раз на ходу как то преобразовывать. Выдача картинки пользователю из БД обойдется гораздо дороже, потому что потребуется скрипт, который прочитает ее из БД и собственно отдаст. Это значительно более ресурсоемко, чем чтение файла и отдача его. Тем более, что в современных web-серверах, вроде nginx этот процесс отлажен настолько, что nginx только связывает поток клиента с файлом да диске, а сама передача происходит на уровне ядра ОС.

Comment: И да, облачные хранилища для файлов выходят в разы дешевле, чем другие виды хранения тех же данных.